# How to extract single value from JSON response after curl REST API call?

Tags: json, shell, rest, curl, grep

I am calling a REST service using curl in a shell script.

```
comp=$(curl -s -H "Accept:application/json" -u $user:password -k https://$host:$port/v/cust?att1=10&att2=11 | grep -o 'true')
```

The REST returns a very simple JSON response:

```
{"Compatible":"true","version":"1}
```

I am trying extract the value true from the response.

```
then if [$comp = "true"]; then
....
fi
```

But the `grep` is not returning the value. `$comp` has the complete response. What am I doing wrong?

I can only use `grep` or `sed` and don't want to have any dependency on others.

Answer (score 0):

The `[$comp = "true"]` must change into `[ $comp = "true" ]`.

There must be a space between the brackets.